# Easier way of converting Json to Java (Jackson)

Tags: java, json, jackson, mapper

I am receiving massive json objects from a service and so far i've been creating POJOs to match the json that comes in.
However, this is getting far too tedious as with every different service I hit I have to build 15-20 new model classes to represent the new service i'm hitting.

In short, what i'm looking for is a way to get a value I need from a neested object in the json as below (sorry for format):

```
random1 {

    random2 {

        arrayOfRandoms

    }

    random3 {

        random4 {

            random5 {
                someValueIWant
            }
        }
    }
}
```

so in this case I want random5s someValueIWant object. I want to get it without creating the models for random1/3/4/5 as i've been doing this whole time.

I should mention that I use Jacksons ObjectMapper to turn the json into java objects.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: You could also let Jackson unmarshal your JSON into a map if it helps.

Comment: Does that mean I could just specify the key I want? what if there are multiple objects with the same name in the json but are actually different objects, so for example, if random2 was called random5 in my above example, I would have two objects with the name random5 but they have different properties. That's how some of the JSON I receive is :(

Comment: You can try JSON path

Comment: JSON path looks like a good candidate, good idea.

Comment: *"I would have two objects with the name random5"* wouldn't matter much, since they aren't on the same "level". The second "random5" is inside "random4", which itself is inside "random3".

Comment: You are looking for json schema generator and then using it while hitting back to those services with data

Answer (score 0):

You could experiment with this online pojo generator:

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

It will generate java classes from plain json (or json schema) and even add jackson annotations.

- Make sure you check "Allow additional properties".
- It requires valid json as input, so don't forget double quotes around fields names and values

If you find yourself doing that often, there's even scriptable versions and maven plugins.